# Why are all files detected as application/octet-stream in nemo?

Tags: mime-types, nemo

`nemo` sees all files as `Binary (application/octet-stream)`, so these kinds of things happened:

- All files (`.mkv`, `.mp4`, `.torrent`, anything) lost their association to any program
- All `.pdf` files could not be opened by `evince`

They are pdfs, however:

```
    $ file bla.pdf
    bla.pdf: PDF document, version 1.4
```

`evince bla.pdf` shows:

```
Unable to open document “file:///tmp/bla.pdf”.
File type application/octet-stream type (application/octet-stream) is not supported
```

Another example:

```
$ file bla.mkv 
bla.mkv: Matroska data
```

But when I right click on `nemo` > properties, it's shown as:

[image]

- What's the possible cause of this problem?
- Is there any package that I should re-install?

#### Info

- I'm using 64-bit ArchLinux.
- The `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` exists
- Installing `gnome-defaults-list` doesn't fix the problem.